# Variable inside if block is shown in call stack even though the if statement didn't get evaluated to true

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I have a piece of code in C as shown below-

In a .c file-

```
1    custom_data_type2 myFunction1(custom_data_type1 a, custom_data_type2 b)
2    {
3        int c=foo();
4        custom_data_type3 t;
5        check_for_ir_path();
6        ...
7        ...
8    }
9
10    custom_data_type4 myFunction2(custom_data_type3 c, const void* d)
11    {
12        custom_data_type4 e;
13        struct custom_data_type5 f;
14        check_for_ir_path();
15        ...
16        temp = myFunction1(...);
17        return temp;
18    }
```

In a header file-

```
1    void CRASH_DUMP(int *i)
2     __attribute__((noinline));
3    
4    #define INTRPT_FORCE_DUMMY_STACK    3
5    
6    #define check_for_ir_path() { \
7        if (checkfunc1() && !checkfunc2()) { \
8            int temp = INTRPT_FORCE_DUMMY_STACK; \
9            ...
10            CRASH_DUMP(&sv);\
11        }\
12    }\
```

In an unknown scenario, there is a crash.
After processing the core dump using GDB, we get the call stack like -

```
#0  0x00007ffa589d9619 in myFunction1 [...] 
(custom_data_type1=0x8080808080808080, custom_data_type2=0x7ff9d77f76b8) at ../xxx/yyy/zzz.c:5

        temp = 32761

        t = <optimized out>



#1  0x00007ffa589d8f91 in myFunction2 [...]

(custom_data_type3=<optimized out>, d=0x7ff9d77f7748) at ../xxx/yyy/zzz.c:16

        temp = 167937677

        f = {

          ...

        }
```

If you see the code, `check_for_ir_path` is invoked from both `myFunction1()` and `myFunction2()`.

And inside `check_for_ir_path`, there is a check inside if block like - `checkfunc1() && !checkfunc2()`. If that check evaluates to TRUE then a SIGSEGV is fired and the process is crashed intentionally. And the variable `temp` is declared only if that condition passes.

Now if you look at the call stack, you can see the local variable `temp` shown even in the *StackFrame_1*. However it didn't crash inside the function `myFunction2`. How could this be possible?

If i declare another variable, say 'int temp' just after the statement `int temp = INTRPT_FORCE_DUMMY_STACK;`, that is not shown as part of *bt full*

How could this be even possible?

Comment: *And the variable sv is declared only if that condition passes.* - No. It can be allocated just anywhere in the function. Most likely in the beginning with all of the rest of automatic variables.

Comment: Compilers are allowed to reorganise any of your code as long as it doesn't change the outcome of the program. In other words - space for the variable maybe allocated even if it's never needed.

Answer (score 4):

Compilers are allowed to reorganise your code in any way that doesn't change the outcome of the program. So if you write:

```
void foo()
{
    if (something)
    {
        int sv;
        ...
    }
}
```

the compiler is allowed to change it into something equivalent to:

```
void foo()
{
    int sv;
    if (something)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

regardless of `something` being true or false.

But the compiler must make sure that this will fail to compile:

```
void foo()
{
    if (something)
    {
        int sv;
        ...
    }
    sv = whatever;  // Compiler error....
}
```

Comment: Okay, i understood.
So as you mentioned yourself the case;


If i had written C code like-

`void foo()
{
    if (something)
    {
        int sv;
        ...
    }
    sv = whatever; 
}`

And the compiler decides to generate an equivalent/optimized code like-

`void foo()
{
    int sv;
    if (something)
    {
        ...
    }
   sv = whatever; 
}`

then how does the compiler ensure the scoping?
Because as per the developer the variable `sv` should not be accessible outside the `if` block.

Comment: @DarshanL The compiler ensures the scoping at compile time. At run time it's a different story. If you make a variable `const` the compiler will make sure you don't change it in any of your code. However, at run time the variable isn't protected and (on most systems) you can write code to change it despite being "const"

Comment: My doubt was different. Do you mean,

If i had written C code like-

`void foo()
{
    if (something)
    {
        int sv;
        ...
    }
    sv = whatever; 
}`

Then compiler won't generate an equivalent/optimized code like-

`void foo()
{
    int sv;
    if (something)
    {
        ...
    }
   sv = whatever; 
}`
Right??

Comment: @DarshanL In the last no code would be generated at all. The compiler would just give you an error and there would be no executable.

Comment: Okay.
Furthermore, referring to the code from my orginal post.
Even though the storage allocation for the variable (`sv`) has happened at the beginning of the function as part of the compiler optimisation, assignment `sv = INTRPT_FORCE_DUMMY_STACK;` will happen only when the `if` condition is evaluated to `TRUE`. Right?
If my understand is right, then from the call stack I see the value of var `sv` is having some garbage value (`32761`). So I can interpret that when the crash happened, the execution was at line - _.h:7_ ?
If `if` block was evaluated to TRUE then `sv should have been 3`